# Separate By Loose Parts without mesh warping

Tags: modeling

[image]Using a game ripped mesh, when I "separate by loose parts" most of the mesh becomes slightly warped causing face warping, except on one part (one arm/part remains normal.) Joining them back together will join them but the warping is still there.

What can I do to separate the parts without deforming them?

note* once the normals and spec are applied... the warping is only visible in the solid shader/sculpt mode.
**if you select a part in object mode and go into sculpt mode this distortion disappears. same if you join them. only the solid mode still has this "problem"
*** once you use material shader view there is no visible issue. so this isn't so much a problem, as a question that might have insight or a solution.

[image]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=X3g6W2qy" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/X3g6W2qy/) no modifiers... if subdivision is added the problem goes away, but Id like to fix this without it

Comment: https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/878733/clip0011.avi....

Comment: .gif has been attached  to the Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I think your Q is a bit out of naming convention (or my understanding).

Mesh is not wrapped, but seems to me as Vertex Normals issue. I had no time to investigate deeper, but disabled **Auto Smooth** Properties > Data > Normals solved it.

[image]

Edit: yet not sure why Auto Smooth react so wierd, but since its Vertex Normal issue it is better to search for **Set Normals from Face** that fix that and you can use Auto Smooth as well.

[image]

There would be still visible edges of separated parts, but that is simply because blender dont know  there is a face next to it so cant optimised. Probably there is another function to search in radious or there is a way to fix it manually, but for sure "seams" are gone when you connect parts together like **Merge by Distance**.

Comment: Thank you so much! When you mentioned normal maps before it got me thinking about it. I'm very new to this kind of thing and all the things I tried I couldn't figure it out. I'm learning this a bit different starting with premade meshes and maps trying to put them together while I learn. Super grateful!